# Firebase SMS Verification / Authentication

Tags: authentication, firebase, twilio, twitter-fabric, vonage

For a client project I'm creating a simple hybrid app that serves a very simple function, yet will have high traffic. The app wouldn't normally need a backend, since it's very very simple, and firebase seems like a perfect solution for the project.

The only part where I'm stuck at is SMS Verification / Authentication with Firebase. However, after some intense googling, and doc reading, I've come to realize that there's no easy way to do this. Here's what I've looked into so far :

1. [Fabric.io Digits](https://get.digits.com/)  has a great JS API, however for some reason firebase and digits won't play nicely together : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/sB7lPuyCVBQ
2. [Facebook Account Kit](https://www.accountkit.com/) - Just a week ago, Facebook released a new kit for SMS Verification & Authentication, although it still feels like it has the same problem as fabric.io digits, at least until proven otherwise.
3. Twilio / Nexmo via NodeJS - These are both epic services with great JS APIs, however from what I understand this would require a separate backend server to handle JWT token exchange. And that on its own is another server, which would become the bottleneck during high traffic, and another point of vulnerability for security, the client team would have to manage separately. Not the most pleasant.
4. Twilio / Nexmo & Auth0 - So far this seems like the best option, where authentication & user management is handled by Auth0, however this solution can quickly get expensive given that both twilio or nexmo and auth0 are paid solutions. Not that I'm a cheapo expecting things to work for free - but feels like a very expensive extra step given that it is just to forward tokens. [see: clients-from-hell]
5. I remember reading somewhere, a suggestion like using phone numbers as emails on firebase like: 123-456-7890@example.com and use the security codes sent over sms as password, which sounds very sketchy for many different reasons.

Usually with hybrid mobile apps, the non-native nature of them or JS APIs are to blame, but for the first time (for me at least) it feels like this isn't the case. I presume at this point Firebase isn't a valid option, but wanted to ask the loving and caring members of the community one last time before starting to look into AWS, and setting up an entire backend for the client.

Is there any other way to handle this type of authentication minus the middle-service / without a backend server? Anyone has any experience using these solutions?

---

**UPDATE : MAY 2017**

[Phone Verification & Authentication is now natively available in Firebase.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth) See my self-posted answer below.

---

**UPDATE : APR 2017**

Firebase now natively supports [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). You can now accomplish this and a lot more using Cloud Functions without setting up any servers.

---

**UPDATE : OCT 2017**

Fabric.io and Firebase has collaborated and integrated [Digits in Firebase phone authentication](https://fabric.io/blog/2017/10/31/fabric-firebase-now-stronger-together/) and launched more features for Fabric.

Comment: Google bought Digits a while back. And yesterday they announced the move from Digits to Firebase Authentication *including* SMS verification. Digits won't be available after September I believe. Login screens are designed by the developer, not provided by the API (unlike what Digits did).

Comment: As soon as this is available I will happily point to this answer. Really exciting news.

Comment: It's available *now*, ready for production. I've just completed my first test.

Comment: I stand corrected! Happily mind blown. Updating now!

Comment: Aand updated, feel free to upvote / promote that and let's hope more people see it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**As of May 17 2017**, the amazing people at Firebase have baked Digits' phone authentication into Firebase. [This is now incredibly easy to achieve natively within Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth), more or less with the flip of a switch and without the need of an external service or anything alike. [You can read more about it in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth) :)

Comment: What is the pricing for this?

Comment: @cprcrack As far as I'm aware, the phone authentication is free. For all other general Firebase pricing info, you can check this out : https://firebase.google.com/pricing

Comment: that would be awesome. I was looking at the pricing page indeed but there's no reference to phone auth. I expected it to be a paid feature because sending SMS can be expensive...

Comment: @cprcrack I stand corrected, unfortunately it is not free. Firebase's pricing page has the latest. As of May 24 2017, it is 1000 verifications = $10 for US, Canada or India. And 1000 verifications = $60 for all other countries.

Comment: It also states that the first 10k verifications are free every month.

Comment: why firebase price is expensive? and the limit of free is only 10K? why not 100K like facebook account kit? why google why?

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to every integration you mentioned, but you might want to try out another one Twilio's services, Authy.

We've recently released production ready code samples via tutorials to help people work through these kinds of problems.

One such example walks you through:

- Sending a OneTouch push notification to mobile Authy app
  or
- Sending a token through mobile Authy app or
- Sending a one-time token in a text message sent with Authy via
  Twilio.

is the [2FA with Authy tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/two-factor-authentication/node/express#0). The following Node.js snippet shows the endpoint waiting for user status to be approved or denied. If the User has approved the OneTouch request, we will save their session as `confirmed`, which officially logs them in.

If the request was denied we render the `/verify` page and ask the User to log in with a Token.

```
// Internal endpoint for checking the status of OneTouch
exports.authyStatus = function(request, response) {
    var status = (request.user) ? request.user.authyStatus : 'unverified';
    if (status == 'approved') {
        request.session.confirmed = true;
        request.session.save(function(err) {
            if (err) return error(response, 500, 
                'There was an error validating your session.');
        });
    }
    if (!request.session) {
        return error(response, 404, 'No valid session found for this user.');
    } else {
        response.send({ status: status });
    }   
};
```

So, this indeed requires you have a server. But given a go at the sample, this should help you decide what will work best for your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot Megan! This inspired a pretty good way to tackle the problem, understand the concept better, and I'll be implementing a solution based on Authy.

Comment: Happy to hear it helped!

Comment: @canozbay with Authy are you not generating custom tokens for firebase?

Comment: @jasan The initial goal was to **not** have a server and just use firebase. I thought this would be possible through Twitter (fabric.io) digits or Facebook Account Kit. Later I realized firebase has no direct integration with these services. Megan's answer gave me an idea, so now instead of having a whole server, and dealing with scaling and uptime problems, I use Amazon Lambda + Authy to generate tokens for firebase.

Comment: @canozbay couldn't you also generate tokens for twitter digits and facebook account kit using Amazon lamba? (i might use google cloud code or the new firebase functions to acheive this)

Comment: @jasan Correct! One could technically do that too. But Fabric Digits Web uses a login popup(!) - a bit of a headache for hybrid apps - And uses URL callbacks, which would mean you have to create additional routes for Lambda (or Cloud Code etc). Also both Facebook and Fabric use a very standard and not-so-customizable login screen. Facebook even puts a large chunk of text under the login button that reads "When you tap Next, Account Kit by Facebook will send you an SMS to confirm your phone number. You don't need a Facebook account" which is just horrible for a client _app_ to have.

Comment: thanks @canozbay digits overs a embed widget as well

Comment: You're welcome @jasan. It does, but unfortunately that also has text under the login button... With client projects, it's a tough sell when there's lots of 3rd party branding :/ Which basically summarizes my love for Authy. No unnecessary branding and easy API :)

Comment: @canozbay: how is the pricing on authy? are you charged everytime user logs to app?

Comment: @jasan I'd suggest checking out their site, as they've flexible pricing. https://www.authy.com/product/pricing/

Comment: @canozbay could you expand your solution as a new answer with some sample code? we're also using firebase and lambda and it'd be great to see how you solved this...

Comment: @Sdude Setting up Firebase / Authy with Lambda wasn't any different than setting them up with nodejs, for which there are lots of examples / tutorials online. The only extra part is setting up routes for AWS Lambda. Which on its own is a separate question in my opinion. I'd suggest either going through AWS's example routes and finding one that matches your needs or taking a look at their step-by-step tutorials.

Comment: @canozbay would you mind pointing me to examples? I'm not sure if you are you generating the firebase tokens in lambda with signInWithCustomToken(), or using the signInWithEmailAndPassword()...

Comment: @SDude We used createCustomToken().. Our project was for advertising and for one of our clients so we couldn't ask for email/pass. It was a very specific use case. So we issued our own tokens instead. Lambda would return the tokens to the client app, then client app would login to firebase using these tokens. After that firebase handles tokens anyway. So for us, Lambda was only needed as a middle-man for the initial sign-up to use a phone number for the lack of a better word.

Comment: @SDude phone authentication / verification is now natively available in Firebase. Definitely go check it out.

Comment: @canozbay Ah yes I saw the announcement, thanks for the pointer anyways! =)

Answer (score 2):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseTooManyRequestsException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class PhoneAutenticationService {
public PhoneAutenticationService(Activity activity,FirebaseAuth auth) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.mAuth = auth;
    setupCallback();
}

private static final String TAG = PhoneAutenticationService.class.getSimpleName();

private Activity activity;
private String verificationCode;
private static final String KEY_VERIFY_IN_PROGRESS = "key_verify_in_progress";

private static final int STATE_INITIALIZED = 1;
private static final int STATE_CODE_SENT = 2;
private static final int STATE_VERIFY_FAILED = 3;
private static final int STATE_VERIFY_SUCCESS = 4;
private static final int STATE_SIGNIN_FAILED = 5;
private static final int STATE_SIGNIN_SUCCESS = 6;

// [START declare_auth]
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
// [END declare_auth]

private boolean mVerificationInProgress = false;
private String mVerificationId;
private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean(KEY_VERIFY_IN_PROGRESS, mVerificationInProgress);
}

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mVerificationInProgress = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_VERIFY_IN_PROGRESS);
}


// [START on_start_check_user]
public void onStart(EditText mPhoneNumberField) {
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    updateUI(currentUser);
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    if (mVerificationInProgress && validatePhoneNumber(mPhoneNumberField)) {
        startPhoneNumberVerification(mPhoneNumberField.getText().toString());
    }
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
}
// [END on_start_check_user]

private void setupCallback(){
    mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
            // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
            // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
            //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
            // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
            //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verificaiton without
            //     user action.
            Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + credential);
            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
            mVerificationInProgress = false;
            // [END_EXCLUDE]

            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
            // Update the UI and attempt sign in with the phone credential
            updateUI(STATE_VERIFY_SUCCESS, credential);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
            // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.
            Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e);
            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
            mVerificationInProgress = false;
            // [END_EXCLUDE]

            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                // Invalid request
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                Toast.makeText(activity,"Invalid phone number.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                Toast.makeText(activity,"Quota exceeded.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }

            // Show a message and update the UI
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            updateUI(STATE_VERIFY_FAILED);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                               PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
            // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
            // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
            // by combining the code with a verification ID.
            Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:" + verificationId);
            Toast.makeText(activity,"onCodeSent:" + verificationId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            verificationCode = verificationId;
            // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
            mVerificationId = verificationId;
            setVerificationCode(verificationId);
            mResendToken = token;

            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            // Update UI
            updateUI(STATE_CODE_SENT);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }

    };
}


public void startPhoneNumberVerification(String phoneNumber) {
    // [START start_phone_auth]
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            activity,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
    // [END start_phone_auth]

    mVerificationInProgress = true;
}



public void verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(String verificationId, String code) {
    // [START verify_with_code]
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);

    // [END verify_with_code]
    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
}

// [START resend_verification]
public void resendVerificationCode(String phoneNumber,
                                   PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            activity,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks);        // resending
    // [END start_phone_auth]
}
// [END resend_verification]

// [START sign_in_with_phone]
public void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(activity, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        Toast.makeText(activity,"signInWithCredential:success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        updateUI(STATE_SIGNIN_SUCCESS, user);
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    } else {
                        // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            // The verification code entered was invalid
                            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                            Toast.makeText(activity,"Invalid code.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            // [END_EXCLUDE]
                        }
                        // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                        // Update UI
                        updateUI(STATE_SIGNIN_FAILED);
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                }
            });
}
// [END sign_in_with_phone]


public void signOut() {
    mAuth.signOut();
    updateUI(STATE_INITIALIZED);
}

private void updateUI(int uiState) {
    updateUI(uiState, mAuth.getCurrentUser(), null);
}

public void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
    if (user != null) {
        updateUI(STATE_SIGNIN_SUCCESS, user);
    } else {
        updateUI(STATE_INITIALIZED);
    }
}

private void updateUI(int uiState, FirebaseUser user) {
    updateUI(uiState, user, null);
}

private void updateUI(int uiState, PhoneAuthCredential cred) {
    updateUI(uiState, null, cred);
}

private void updateUI(int uiState, FirebaseUser user, PhoneAuthCredential cred) {
    switch (uiState) {
        case STATE_INITIALIZED:
            // Initialized state, show only the phone number field and start button
            Toast.makeText(activity,"Initialized state",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case STATE_CODE_SENT:
            // Code sent state, show the verification field, the
            Toast.makeText(activity,"Code sent state",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;
        case STATE_VERIFY_FAILED:
            // Verification has failed, show all options
            Toast.makeText(activity,"Verification has failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;
        case STATE_VERIFY_SUCCESS:
            // Verification has succeeded, proceed to firebase sign in
            Toast.makeText(activity,"Verification has succeeded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Set the verification text based on the credential
            if (cred != null) {
                if (cred.getSmsCode() != null) {
                    //mVerificationField.setText(cred.getSmsCode());
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(activity,"Invalid verification code.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            break;
        case STATE_SIGNIN_FAILED:
            // No-op, handled by sign-in check
            Toast.makeText(activity,"Sign in failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;
        case STATE_SIGNIN_SUCCESS:
            // Np-op, handled by sign-in check
            Toast.makeText(activity,"Sign in sucesssss!!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }

    if (user == null) {
        // Signed out

    } else {
        // Signed in
    }
}


public boolean validatePhoneNumber(EditText mPhoneNumberField) {
    String phoneNumber = mPhoneNumberField.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber) || phoneNumber.length()>10 || phoneNumber.length()<9) {
        Toast.makeText(activity,"Invalid phone number.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks getmCallbacks() {
    return mCallbacks;
}

public PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken getmResendToken() {
    return mResendToken;
}

public FirebaseAuth getmAuth() {
    return mAuth;
}

public String getVerificationCode() {
    return verificationCode;
}

public void setVerificationCode(String verificationCode) {
    this.verificationCode = verificationCode;
}
```

}

In your activity initialize Firebase auth and listener

```
 mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // ...
        }
    };


    //init all auth process
    phoneAutenticationService = new PhoneAutenticationService(this,mAuth);

 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    getActivity().registerReceiver(smsBroadcastReceiver, filter);// define e broadcast receiver to intercept a sms verification code
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);sms code
    }
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(smsBroadcastReceiver);

}
```

and finally call firebase method for authentication

```
public void startAuthenticationByPhone(){
    if (!validatePhoneNumber(phoneInput)) {
        return;
    }
    startPhoneNumberVerification(phoneInput.getText().toString());

}......
```

Answer (score 0):

**Now phone auth is available in firebase.Here is Code for Phone Auth using Firebase:**

```
EditText phoneNum,Code;// two edit text one for enter phone number other for enter OTP code
Button sent_,Verify;// sent button to request for verification and verify is for to verify code
private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private String mVerificationId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_number_auth);

    phoneNum =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.fn_num);
    Code =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.code);

    sent_ =(Button)findViewById(R.id.sent_nu);
    Verify =(Button)findViewById(R.id.verify);

    callback_verificvation();               ///function initialization

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    sent_.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String num=phoneNum.getText().toString();
            startPhoneNumberVerification(num);          // call function for receive OTP 6 digit code
        }
    });
    Verify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String code=Code.getText().toString();
            verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(mVerificationId,code);            //call function for verify code 

        }
    });
}

private void startPhoneNumberVerification(String phoneNumber) {
    // [START start_phone_auth]
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
    // [END start_phone_auth]


}

private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information

                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sign in successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI

                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            // The verification code entered was invalid

                        }


                    }
                }
            });
}
private void verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(String verificationId, String code) {
    // [START verify_with_code]
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
    // [END verify_with_code]
    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
}


private void callback_verificvation() {

    mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
            // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
            // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
            //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
            // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
            //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verificaiton without
            //     user action.





            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
            // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.


            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                // Invalid request

            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded

            }

            // Show a message and update the UI

        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                               PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
            // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
            // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
            // by combining the code with a verification ID.


            // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
            mVerificationId = verificationId;
            mResendToken = token;


        }
    };
```