# How to implement SMS / 2FA Verification using Authy+Amazon lambda+Firebase?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, twilio, firebase-authentication, authy

I have developed an Android App using Firebase as a backend to store data.

During the development of my app, I have been Using Firebase's Email+password Authentication method for the sake of simplicity, in which I enter the Phone Number, Email and Password during Login or Signup and make the phone number as the Unique Identifier for each user.

Here is how my database tree looks like:

```
Root
 + friends 
 - users
    - 9xx888xxx
         hasLoggedIn: false
         name:"XXXXXXXXXX"
         phoneNumber:"9xx888xxx"
       + timeStampJoinedaddclose
   + 989xxxx898
   + xxxx000000
```

Note that the Phone Number acts as the UID so it must be validated through SMS verification or something like that.

Now as my application has been developed, I want to switch from Firebase's Email+Password Authentication to SMS Verification method.So I googled it and come across this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694791/firebase-sms-verification-authentication).

As I am new to development, I dont know how to implement this type of Verification using AUTHY + Amazon Lambda + Firebase. I have seen the tutorial on Twilio's website about Authy, but it can't help me.

Can someone please guide me or help me in right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did u find anything?

Comment: @GabbarSingh not yet :-(

Comment: @GabbarSingh take a look at my answer below. Google now has a new product called Cloud Functions and a tutorial to explain most of what you'd need to address this problem :)

Answer (score 2):

As of yesterday, May 17 2017, Firebase supports this natively! :)

[I believe they're writing the docs for Android as I write this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth). 
However, here's the docs for this new Firebase feature on [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth) and [Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth).